# Determine the last two digits of $97^{84002}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Determine the last two digits of $97^{84002}$

**Answer** is $09$.

I learned that in the case the unit digit ends in $7$ we could use

$(..7)^x \Rightarrow (..7^4)^{\frac{x}{4}} \Rightarrow (..1)^{\frac{x}{4}}$

In this case "$x$" is not divisible by $4$ so I am stuck.

Comment: Hint: $$97^{100}\equiv1\mod{100}$$

Comment: The point is to recognize a pattern here.  Just looking at the last digit for now, if you look at the pattern of $7^n$ the last digits are $7,9,3,1,7,9,3,1,7,9,3,1,\dots$.  Its not a problem that your exponent isn't divisible by $4$.  What is important here is how close to being a multiple of four it is.  If it were one more than a multiple of four then you'd get one result.  If it were two more than a multiple of four you'd get a different result, etc...

Comment: $97\equiv-3\bmod100$, so what is $97^2\bmod 100$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner $97^2\mod{100}$ is the answer :) P.S. How do I stop the annoying spaces with \mod?

Comment: @DonThousand:  it's not the answer -- the answer is 09 -- but it's a big hint; try \bmod

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I'm pretty sure it is the answer, though. And I'll try it.

Comment: @don you might also want to check $97^{20}$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi may be referring to the Carmichael function of $100$ being $20$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Ohhhh, I gotchu.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

The simplest consists in using congruences mod. $100$ and Euler's theorem. Note that $\varphi(100)=40$. So as $97$ and $100$ are coprime, we have
$$97^{84002}\equiv 97^{84002\bmod 40}=97^2\mod100.$$

Answer (score 0):

We essentially need $97^{20n+2}\pmod{100}$ where $n$ is a positive integer

First of all, $97\equiv-3\pmod{100}$

$97^{20n+2}=(97^2)^{10n+1}\equiv((-3)^2)^{10n+1}\equiv3^{20n+2}\pmod{100}$

Now using http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html

$\lambda(100)=[\lambda(25),\lambda(4)]=\cdots=20$

For $(a,100)=1,$ $$a^{20n+2}=a^2\cdot(a^{20})^n\equiv a^2\cdot 1^n\pmod{100}$$

Here $a=3$